# 2014 anti-virus prevention in Ubuntu: AVG deb is missing?

Tags: antivirus

While I am usually singing linux/ubuntu's praises, I am frustrated lately in the anti-virus department.  I like to scan my windows flash drive and occassionally my whole linux HDD for viruses using my xubuntu 12.04 LTS setup.  clamTK gives me too many false alerts to use it for a whole HDD and now AVG seems to have cancelled its .deb file for the terminal scanner.  While I wish AVG had a GUI, I miss its quick, efficient scans.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Antivirus/Avg

the first link below seems to recommend Comodo.  I have no experience with Comodo and seems to be an always running cumbersome AV.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Antivirus

```
https://www.comodo.com/home/download/download.php?prod=antivirus-for-linux
```

I know many linux users think that AV is not necessary for linux/BSD, but I was wondering what the rest of us are using in 2014 ?  A thorough AV engine with a simple GUI would be great.

Please help,
LBjr

Comment: I think you can still download the linux `.deb` file from [this page](http://free.avg.com/us-en/download-free-all-product), although I haven't installed it myself so don't know if it still works correctly.

Comment: found it here & yes it still works great

Answer (score -1):

found it here & yes it still works great –

http://free.avg.com/us-en/download-free-all-product